# Is it possible to recognize non-verbal words using Google Speech or IBM Watson?

Tags: speech-recognition, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

Is it possible to recognize non-verbal expressions or to customize the tool (Google Speech / IBM Watson) for this? Non-verbal expressions are pauses during speech, for example:

```
"hum... i would like to know hum... how do i connect YouTube to Google AdSense"
```

In the tests I have done so far this type of expression is ignored in the transcript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM Watson Speech to Text service rolls up these as `%HESITATION`. if you are not seeing this then you might have the smart formatting option on, which you will need to switch off.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-basic-response#hesitation